# c++ template function specialization - wrong number of template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Okay, so I'm just learning about templates. Anyways, I'm probably (most definitely) doing something wrong, but here's the problem:

My first template function is declared like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& printFormatted(T const& container, std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    //...
}
```

Then I'm supposed to implement a specialized case for maps, so this is what I tried to do:

```
template<>
std::ostream& printFormatted<std::map<typename key, typename value>>(std::map<typename key, typename value> const& container, std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    //...
}
```

I might be making a mistake with my key/value variables, not sure, but regardless, when trying to compile I get the error message:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
error: provided for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Allocator> class std::__debug::map’
```

Clearly there's something I don't understand about templates or maps? Someone please help?

Comment: Are `key` and `value` actual types in your code or do you intend them as placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your uses of `key` and `value` are meant to be placeholers, you cannot declare template parameters inline with the keyword `typename`. That is to say, `Foo<typename T>` is always invalid -- but not to be mistaken with `Foo<typename T::bar>` which is different altogether. The syntax for specialization looks like:

```
// Declare template parameters up front
template<typename Key, typename Value>
std::ostream&
printFormatted<std::map<Key, Value> >(std::map<Key, Value> const& container, std::ostream& os = std::cout);
```

but that wouldn't work because it's a *partial* specialization and those are not allowed for function templates. Use overloading instead:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
std::ostream&
printFormatted(std::map<Key, Value> const& container, std::ostream& os = std::cout);
```

This overload will be preferred over the more general template.

Comment: That only matches maps with `less<K>` and `std::allocator`, though :-(

Comment: Thanks, this fixed things up perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is not full specialization, but *partial* specialization, since you still have a template, only a more specialized one. However, you cannot partially specialize functions, so instead, we just provide a new overload. For `std::map`, you need four template parameters (as the error message helpfully tells you):

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Comp, typename Alloc>
std::ostream & printFormatted(const std::map<K,V,Comp,Alloc> & m,
                              std::ostream & o = std::cout)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is not relevant to C++11**

If you're using a pre-c++11 compiler, you can't use `>>` when closing nested templates. You need a space between the `>`s.

C++ sees `>>` as a different token than `>`, and the compiler doesn't use it to close templates.  You need a space so the compiler sees a `>` followed by a `>`.

The following is more likely to work:

```
template<>
std::ostream& printFormatted<std::map<typename key, typename value> >(std::map<typename         key, typename value> const& container, std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: That was actually fixed in C++0x / C++11

Comment: Fantastic! I hadn't heard that, and it drove me nuts when I was just starting C++.  I'll leave this answer up to help anyone using an old compiler, but edit it to clarify that point.